# Kotlin generic classes

Tags: class, generics, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and am trying to access a specific field within a generic class

I have tried all sorts of potential solutions - The problem that I have is that I don't know how to inform Kotlin that the field name in the class that I pass across exists.

This is my class :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "coursemark_table")
@Parcelize
class CourseMark(
    @field:PrimaryKey
    @field:ColumnInfo(name = "coursemark_number")
    var number: Int,
    var name: String,
    var latitude: String,
    var longitude: String,
    var passTo: String
): Parcelable
```

This is the generic list adapter class that I am trying to initialise - I can't work out how to get at the name field in CourseMark in the OnBindViewHolder function I can understand why since BaseListHolder has no knowledge of the field names in CourseMark until it is initialised but there must be a way of telling the Kotlin compiler that this field exists - My apologies for posting this but I have been struggling for a number of days to figure this out :-

```
abstract class BaseListAdapter<T> internal constructor(context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseListAdapter<T>.BaseViewHolder>() {

    private val mInflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    private var mMarks = emptyList<T>() // Cached copy of marks

    inner class BaseViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val markItemView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BaseViewHolder {
        val itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_coursemark, parent, false)
        return BaseViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val current = mMarks[position]
        holder.markItemView.text = current.name
    }

    /**
     * Associate a list of marks with this adapter
     */

    internal fun setMarks(marks: List<T>) {
        mMarks = marks
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    // getItemCount() is called many times, and when it is first called,
    // mMarks has not been updated (means initially, it's null, and we can't return null).
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mMarks.size
    }

    /**
     * Get the mark at a given position.
     * This method is useful for identifying which mark
     * was clicked or swiped in methods that handle user events.
     *
     * @param position
     * @return The mark at the given position
     */
    fun getMarkAtPosition(position: Int): T {
        return mMarks[position]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to implement your `RecyclerView.Adapter` with the specified type, `CourseMark`. I'm not clear on why you are keeping your adapter generic, when you are inflating a layout that looks like it is specific to the class `CourseMark`.

If however, you really do want to keep this generic, you can leverage Kotlin's smart casting in your `onBindViewHolder` method:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val current = mMarks[position]
    if(current is CourseMark){
         holder.markItemView.text = current.name
    }
}
```

Comment: Elli - Thanks so much for this - As you can see I am pretty new to Kotlin and I will take your comments on board.

Comment: Great. If this solves your question, don't forget to upvote and accept the answer!